# MS Access : SQL Query "Union All"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have the Following problem , I have a form for which I created a combobox that I use to Filter. My Row Source SQL Query looks like this :

```
SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName,Employee_ComboBox.FirstName, Employee_ComboBox.ID,Employee_ComboBox.OperatingEntity,Employee_ComboBox.OrganisationNameFull
FROM Employee_ComboBox
ORDER BY Employee_ComboBox.[ID];
```

I Would like to Add `UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM` so that I get (All) in my combobox.The Problem is I don't know how to add more than 1 Column to the SQL Query. I tried something like :

`SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName FROM Employee_ComboBox UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM Employee_ComboBox;`
This Works ,but when I try to Add other Columns I Do something wrong..Example :

```
SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName,Employee_ComboBox.FirstName FROM Employee_ComboBox UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM Employee_ComboBox;
```

Any Ideas on how I can Add all the columns and the (All) Value in my Combobox?

Br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. no of columns should be equal in both candidates of joins

```
SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName, Employee_ComboBox.FirstName
    FROM Employee_ComboBox
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "(All)" as LastName,"" as FirstName FROM Employee_ComboBox;
```

Comment: Yes,this is what I was Looking for.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add values for them so the subqueries for the `UNION` have the same number of columns.  `NULL` is often a reasonable value:

```
SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName, Employee_ComboBox.FirstName
FROM Employee_ComboBox
UNION ALL
SELECT "(All)", NULL FROM Employee_ComboBox;
```

You might want the empty string instead.  Also, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates, which is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks,this looks great .. But I tried to add after `SELECT Employee_ComboBox.LastName, Employee_ComboBox.FirstName, Employee_ComboBox.ID` and it doesn't work. I receive an error message : "the number of columns in the two selected tabels or queries of a union query do not match" .. What am I missing, do I need to add Something ales when adding 1 more column?